# Pass by value result with exceptions

Tags: programming-languages, exceptions, exception-handling

I have a doubt with the pass-by-value-result method. As far as I understood, it passess the value of the parameter to the function, and then get the result as the function ends. But what happens with exceptions? I mean, with the following code:

```
int x = 1
void g(value-result int y) {
     y = 5
     throw E;
}
try {
    g(x);
} catch E {
    // do nothing
};
print_value(x);
```

What is the printed value? At the time the exception is throw, the local variable of g is equal to 5. However, the function does not terminate correctly, so my question is: does the `y=5` statement actually modify the variable x, and then it is printed 5, or since an exception is thrown, then the function does not terminate correctly and thus 5 is not given as result to x, and hence it is printed 1? My guess is that since an exception is an abnormal termination, x should not take 5. Is this correct?

Comment: What language is this?  It appears to use C-like syntax, but the "value-result" modifier isn't from anything I'm familiar with.

Comment: @MasonWheeler - it looks like C-like psuedocode. Pass-by-value-result is (afaik) only implemented in Ada.

Comment: I don't know of any language actually using pbvr except Ada (for `IN OUT` parameters), so it's probably pseudo-code.

Comment: I don't think it's productive to ask edge-case questions about fictional languages.

Answer (score 3):

Ultimately, it depends on the specification of the particular language that you are using, but in general, [pass-by-value-result (Wikipedia)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Evaluation_strategy#Call_by_copy-restore) means that the original value of the caller will not be modified until the function returns, so the only reasonable thing to expect is that the value should remain unchanged in the event of an exception, because when an exception is thrown the function cannot really be said to return.